# "He hit my head." or "He hit me in/on the head."

Tags: grammar

Why do we need the preposition 'in' or 'on'? Can't we simply say "He hit my head."?

Comment: This is a seemingly very simple question, but I couldn't come up with even a quick comment, let alone the framework for a properly detailed answer. Even claiming that *he hit me on the head* is a short way of saying *he hit me on **the top of** my head* is unsatisfactory when you could also just say *he hit the top of my head*. It might be as simplistic as saying almost everything can be expressed in different words, and that's just how language evolves, but I keep thinking there's a more direct answer than that. I just can't think of it.

Comment: I'm curious if this boils down to *Why do we have multiple ways of expressing the same thing?* or if it really is specific to this one type of phrase—or prepositions in general. The short answer is we don't ***need*** the preposition in this example. But it also seems to me (in a way I can't express) that it's more than merely superfluous.

Comment: You can use all three.  "In" and "on" have slightly different connotations, but too subtle to define outside of a specific context.

Comment: Does it sound natural to just say 'He hit my head' without the preposition in/on? Among the three, which sentence would you use?

Comment: What is your context???

Comment: @mizumiki17 I personally would never use *in*, but I know other people do. I could say either of the other two. However, I'm probably more likely to say *he hit me on the head*. But note this actual distinction—and finally useful comment: (1) ✔ *He hit my head with a car.* (2) ✔ *He hit the top of my head with a car.* (3) ✘ *He hit me **on the head** with a car.*

Comment: What about if I get hit with an object, for example, (1) He hit me on the head with a baseball bat. or (2) He hit my head with a baseball bat. Thanks @JasonBassford

Comment: @mizumiki17 Both of those baseball bat sentences are equally likely and meaningful.

Comment: It should be "I bopped her on the bean with a rotten tangerine".